# cosineSimilarity cannot implicitly cast def [org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.vectors.DenseVectorScriptDocValues] to java.lang.String

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, cosine-similarity

I have an error that i don't understand on es with CosineSimilarity

My goal is to make similarity search on two fiels name and description,

An api give the $query_vector param and this value is good,

I also can index document with vector,

here my es request:

```
{
            "size":10,
            "query": {
                "script_score": {
                    "query": {"match_all": {}},
                    "script": {
                        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['name_vector2']) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['description_vector2']) + 2.0",
                        "params": {
                            "query_vector": $query_vector
                        
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "_source": {"includes": ["name", "description"]}
        }
```

give me this error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "runtime error",
            "script_stack": ["cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['name_vector2']) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['description_vector2']) + 2.0", " ^---- HERE"],
            "script": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['name_vector2']) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['description_vector2']) + 2.0",
            "lang": "painless",
            "position": {
                "offset": 41,
                "start": 0,
                "end": 132
            }
        }],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [{
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "demandes_internes",
            "node": "4_1L4y7rTd-VrfOktvr-eQ",
            "reason": {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "runtime error",
                "script_stack": ["cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['name_vector2']) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['description_vector2']) + 2.0", " ^---- HERE"],
                "script": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['name_vector2']) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['description_vector2']) + 2.0",
                "lang": "painless",
                "position": {
                    "offset": 41,
                    "start": 0,
                    "end": 132
                },
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "class_cast_exception",
                    "reason": "cannot implicitly cast def [org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.vectors.DenseVectorScriptDocValues] to java.lang.String"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

result of the GET _cluster/health?pretty

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "ent",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 8,
  "active_shards" : 8,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 1,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 88.88888888888889
}
```

I have tried to increase max_buckets but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'name_vector2')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).